# How can I edit an embed color with my discord bot with discord.py

Tags: python, embed, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a discord bot for fun. I was wondering how I could use edit_message to change the embed color of the message.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(self):
    """Embed color changing"""
    em1 = discord.Embed(title="Red", colour=0xFF0000)
    msg = await self.message.channel.send(embed=em1)
    em2 = discord.Embed(title="Green", colour=0x00FF00)
    await self.bot.edit_message(msg, embed=em2)
```

When I run the command I get this error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
>   exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute
>   'edit_message'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of discord.py are you using? Your code looks like it was written for v0.16 or older.

After v1.0.0 you would use [Message.edit()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20edit#discord.Message.edit)

`await msg.edit(embed=em2)`

Comment: I am using discord.py rewrite. Thank you for the help! it works now :)

Answer (score -1):

also did you try color with the "u" like: color=0xFF0000

Comment: The question is more than a year old. So you can't expect an answer. Also what you posted is not an answer to the question.